# How to generate Code in pre existing code files in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation

I just found out how to generate code using [annotation processing](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder)

But as I understand these are just additional code files.

What i want to achieve is something like this (In a already existing file):

```
@basicMethod
public void executeStuff(String help, int me) {
    mySystem.executor(help, me); // <- This should be generated by this annotation
}
```

Is there any way to achieve something like this?

Also, I am not sticking to Annotations. Any other way would also be helpful.

Comment: With intended methods, this is not possible. We can only generate code for new classes, not modify existing classes. That being said, Lombok found a way through undocumented compiler APIs. They get the AST before compilation, manipulate the AST and thus modify existing classes.

Comment: @Turing85 I heard about project Lombok. Does "undocumented compiler APIs" mean it is not documented anywhere and is done by reverse engineering?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Another downside is that this API could change without further notice (it happened once in the past, I think).